# What is the probability that the center of the interval belongs to a specific range?

Tags: probability, self-study

**Problem**

> Two points L and M belongs to the interval [0, 1] are chosen at
>   random. Thus, the interval is divided into 3 smaller sections.
>
> What is the probability that the center of the interval LM belongs to
>   [0, 1/3]?

**Attempted Solution**

Why is this not correct,

$\Rightarrow 0< \frac{M-L}{2}<\frac{1}{3} $

But, the following is correct?

$\Rightarrow 0< \frac{M+L}{2}<\frac{1}{3} $

[image]

So, according to this picture, the middle position of $LM$ lies in $[0, \frac{1}{3}]$, if $LM$ itself lies in $[0, \frac{2}{3}]$.

What is $LM$ here?

Isn't that $M-L$?

Answer (score 1):

The center of the interval is the midpoint between M and L which is (M+L)/2.  So the probability that the midpoint is in the interval [0,1/3] is $P[0<(M+l)/2<1/3]$.

Comment: plz, see the picture.

Comment: Anonymous, this answer is correct: the midpoint of any interval $[L,M]$ is the mean of the endpoints $(M+L)/2$.  In your picture you always seem to pick $L=0$, but obviously that's not random, indicating the picture does not correctly reflect the problem.